# Using a .NET hashing class within a VBA Project

Tags: .net, vba

I am trying to create a hash function to use within an Excel macro. I found a function someone created that works but creates a HMAC using HMACSHA1.

```
Public Function Base64_HMACSHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String)
    Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    Base64_HMACSHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing

End Function
```

This seems to be using a .NET class using the [System.Security.Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=net-5.0) Namespace. When I try to use another class within this namespace such as SHA1, SHA512 or even HMACSHA512 I get a runtime error:

SHA1: Runtime error code 429

SHA512: Runtime error code 429

HMAC512: -2146233079 (80131509)

How does this function work only with the HMACSHA1 class and not the rest?

I have looked at the documentation but the examples provided for these classes are utilizing C#. Any direction in ways to implement these would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Side Note: There are online converters that can translate C# to VB.NET. It does a good job for translating examples. From VB.NET to VBA, is less easy, but they're very similar. Many of the objects and classes in VB.NET wont be available in VBA, some will be able to be added to the project through references.

Comment: This may be of interest  'https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to freeflows comment I was able to identify the errors were being caused by not having the correct .NET framework enabled. Majority of these classes require version 3.5 to be enabled. HMACSHA1 seems to be the only SHA function to work without having 3.5 enabled.

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA

A slight correction needs to be added to that article as it says that .NET 3.5 needs to be installed, version 3.5 is a subset of .NET 4.0 and higher on Windows 10 however is not enabled by default. Some application installers will enable it but not all do. Version 3.5 can be enabled using the Turn Windows Features on and off tool.

https://superuser.com/questions/1575929/program-installer-requires-net-framework-3-5-but-i-have-4-8